# Problem in loop through span elements using python Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

Objective: To loop over Span items (inform of buttons) on a Web Page and get corresponding href values. This page can have multiple buttons kind of elements and its dynamic and will have value from 1 to n.

Input html code:

[image]

and this class='mb-text' values varies from 1 to n.

So Now I need to find if this span class exist and if exist, then loop through it and get all href related to those

The below statements were not able to locate intended elements returned empty list

```
elements1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("(//span[contains(@class,'mb-text')])")
elements1 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('maxbutton-1 maxbutton maxbutton-download-link')
```

Please suggest

Comment: can you share the url?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing a wait before accessing these elements.
Please try this:

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class,'mb-text')]")))
time.sleep(1)
elements1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class,'mb-text')]")
```

You will need these imports:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
```

Also possibly there is an iframe there.
If so you will have to switch into that iframe.

Comment: No luck buddy. I guess its not problem I see with time wait. But I am doing some mistake to select by xpath or css from input of html which I have given in original post. Not sure what I am missing, since its returning empty list. I need some suggestion how to correctly access those elements based on html given in original post

Comment: can you share a link to that page?